# Not receving Bitcoins to my testnet wallet

Tags: wallet, testnet, bitcoinj, faucets

I am running the `bitcoinj` `wallettemplate` on `testnet3`. I have this address `miAKWcmebJ7TYyZCYUx54djHsatVGdNZA8` , I tried out some websites which sends me `testnet` coins (Faucet). But I am not receiving any. ? What I am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found this [one](https://accounts.blockcypher.com/testnet-faucet). this was the only one which was working.
I tested on some coins and send them back.